# Static file not load in django template?

Tags: django, python-3.x

> Problem is STatic file not load.

```
 CRM/
 |    |-- CRM/
 |    |-- next_crm/
 |    |-- static/
 |    |    +-- css/
 |    |         +-- bootstrap.min.css    <-- here
 |    +-- manage.py
```

> This is my static variables defined in the
>   next_crm/settings/settings.py file.

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

Comment: how you are refrecing the file in template?

Comment: next_crm>html>login.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your primary project folder (CRM, in this case) you have added the urls.py static debug lines?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings 
...
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My settings.py are:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Comment: File "F:\python\CRM\next_crm\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined

Comment: add in CRM/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I also face this type of problem few days ago.
but found a solution for this.Add these lines to load static in settings.py

```
STATICFILE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), "static")
```

instead of this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

Hope this will solve your problem. :)